# using p:dialog in ui:composition

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page inner.xhtml included in outer.xhtml using ui:include. The inner.xhtml has a p:commandLink whose oncomplete attribute opens a p:dialog.

**inner.xhtml**

```
<html>
 <ui:composition>
  <h:form>
   <p:commandLink oncomplete="mydialog.show();" actionListener="listener method" process="@this">
   </p:commandLink>
  </h:form>
 </ui:composition>
 <p:dialog id="mydialogid" widgetVar="mydialog">
   My Code For Dialog
 </p:dialog>
</html>
```

**outer.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
<p:commandButton oncomplete="dlg.show();" actionListener="listener method" global="false"></p:commandButton>
</h:form>
<p:dialog id="dlgid" widgetVar="dlg" dynamic="true" appendTo="@(body)">
    <ui:include src="inner.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="idPrefix" value="par"/>
    </ui:include>
</p:dialog>
```

The problem is that on click of commandlink in inner.xhtml i am getting this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mydialog is not defined
```

And the dialog is not opening. How to fix this?

I am using primefaces 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the PrimeFaces documentation.

You need to do:-

```
<p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('mydialog').show();">
```

I'm having a problem with `oncomplete` at the moment, so if that doesn't work, rule out this problem by trying:-

```
<p:commandButton onclick="PF('mydialog').show();">
```